# JDBC SQL Exception Data Source not found in servlets

Tags: servlets, jdbc, sqlexception

I have created a database : Admission.mdb, and added it to the user DNS : "adm"
When I try to access it through java program, I use following code to connect the database

Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:adm");

It worrks properly, and the program can access the database.
But, when I tried to use the same code inside a servlet, it gives following Exception:
"java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified"
Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to indicate where the `mdb` file is (and what is its name). Take a look at [this](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=2691&lngWId=2)

Comment: I am doing it the same way it is described in that page.
I am using the Step2 : Method 2. i.e. 

DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:"+dnsname)

And I am sure, the DNS it set up preperly, because as I mentioned in the question, it works for any normal program except the servlets

Comment: You should post the exact code you are using and where is your mdb file in your web application.

Comment: Never mind, I understood what was the problem. Changed the User DNS to System DNS. That did it. Thanks for your efforts :)